# Equation of Locus of a point

Tags: analytic-geometry

For the variable triangle $ABC$ with the fixed vertex at $C(1,2)$ and $A,B$ having co ordinates $(\cos t, \sin t)$, $(\sin t, -\cos t)$ respectively, find the locus of its centroid.

Plz help me, I could not even get how to start.

Comment: Start sketching and plotting the centroid for different values of $t$ to find out the general shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

I would say, coordinates of the centroid of the triangle:

$x_{ce}=\frac{x_A+x_B+x_C}{3},\quad y_{ce}=\frac{y_A+y_B+y_C}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Use the [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_triangle_and_tetrahedron) that, for  triangle, of vertices $A=(x_A,y_A)$, $B=(x_B,y_B)$, $C=(x_C,y_C)$, the centroid $M$ has coordinates:
$$
(x_M,y,M)=\left(\frac{x_A+x_B+x_C}{3},\frac{y_A+y_B+y_C}{3} \right)
$$